# What's the word for "implying there will be a negative outcome"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Someone just said to me "Let's do that.. and we'll see how that turns out".  The tone of the voice implied that the "we'll see how that turns out" was doomed to failure and pain and that the decision to proceed with that course of action was flawed.

What's the word for "implying there will be a negative outcome"?

I can think of a couple of words such as "fatalistic" and "brinkmanship" but neither is quite right. "Sarcasm" isn't it either as I am not focusing on the outcome more so the feeling. It's not Snide or Snarky or Pompous as it was not said with superiority. "Resigned" comes close. Does anyone else have any ideas?

BTW - The situation has passed, it's just bugging me that I can't "tag" it with the correct word (and I don't want to have to wake up at 3am when my brain finally responds with the word).

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried thesaurus? pessimistic, maybe? skeptical? demoralized? despondent? dejected? defeatist?

Comment: **Consequences** mostly imply negative outcomes. *"Do as I say, or face the consequences"*.

Comment: Leery might work in that context, but I'm leery of its being the definitive answer.

Comment: There is an *implied threat*. He's *insinuating violence*.

Comment: Could be [gallows humor](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/gallows-humor), depending on how it's spoken.

Comment: There's always "naysaying".

Comment: If it is a work environment, then 'jaded' works.

Answer (score 2):

[Pessimism](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pessimism) -- an inclination to emphasize adverse aspects, conditions, and possibilities or to expect the worst possible outcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Foreboding** (n): a feeling that something bad is going to happen

**Foreboding** (adj):  indicative of or marked by foreboding

Source: Merriam Webster

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foreboding